Elastic Beanstalk fails to run any operation
I have an AWS-EB environment (Java on Tomcat) that won't success to deploy any app. The only way I CAN successfuly deploy a version, is by stopping the EC2 instance of the environment, restart it and then to deploy. Then, the version will successfuly be deployed (but a "502 bad gateway" will be shown, and the only way to solve THAT is by switching from load balancer to single instance and back to load balancer) but the next deployment will fail. When I request app logs, it fails too.
The events section after trying to deploy a new version
I tried to reboot the EC2 instance: from the Elastic Beanstalk console, the reboot fails, from the EC2 console, it success but doesn't help.

It's probably instance size is too small for your app and running out of memory space. But you need to look into eb-engine.log to find out what's going on. If you can't connect to ssh, or get logs, then you're out of memory for sure.
